# Counter for calculate number of runs in java

Tags: java

Here is my code which take an input value and compare it with a random value 
I have 15 times to run the code to estimate and get the input value equals to the random value which the code decide ... 
I want to make a counter to calculate how many times I did run the code ...
I tried to put count++; in different places in the code but I did not get right answer ... Where do you think that count++; should be put to get number of runs in the out put ...
thanks

Here is my code

```
package person;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cat {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int max = 100;
        int min = 0;
        int diff = max-min;
        Random rn = new Random();
        int i = rn.nextInt(diff+1);
        i+=min;
        for (int k=0; k<15; k++){
          int count=0;
          Scanner sb = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Enter your number");
          int x = sb.nextInt();
          if(x>i){
            System.out.println(x+"is bigger than i");
          } else if(x<i){
            System.out.println(x+"is smaller than i");
          } else if (x==i){
            System.out.println(x+"is equals to i "+" "+" no. of try"+count);
            break;
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You must store the value of count in a file in order to know how many times you run the code.

Comment: @Mr.Robot I cant believe you just told him that, its totally wrong!

Comment: You should also move your Scanner out of the loop so you aren't creating one on each iteration.

Comment: I see this "Resource leak: 'sb' is never closed" as a comment next to the Scanner , it does not make any problem but how to fix the code to remove this comment "Resource leak: 'sb' is never closed" ..thanks

Comment: At the end check if sb is not null then do sb.close();

Comment: where I put it in the code ? is it after for loop or what?

Comment: Yes check the edit !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your approach was that you count was in the loop so it would always be reseted. you can move it outside the loop or just print the counter loop variable.

```
package person;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cat {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int max = 100;
        int min = 0;
        int diff = max-min;
        Random rn = new Random();
        int i = rn.nextInt(diff+1);
        i+=min;
        int k;
        for (k=0; k<15; k++) {
            Scanner sb = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter your number");
            int x = sb.nextInt();
            if(x>i) {
                System.out.println(x+"is bigger than i");
            } else if(x<i) {
                System.out.println(x+"is smaller than i");
            } else if (x==i) {
                System.out.println(x+"is equals to i "+" "+" no. of try"+k+1);
                break;    
            }
        }
        if(sb !=null) {
            sb.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you .. when I try 5 times the output is 4 ... What to do to correct the output?

Comment: Since you K runs from 0...15 you need to do k+1 or you can run from 1 ... 15 with the loop condition k<=15.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're setting count = 0 in your for loop. move

```
int count = 0;
```

above the for loop and add

```
count++;
```

at the beginning of the for-loop. If you had it at the end, you wouldn't count the last run when the loop might break out. Having it at the beginning of the loop means you definitely count each time you even start the process of looking for the randomly generated number.

But it would actually be better to just use the look counter k to keep track of the number of time. No need to waste the extra space on another variable when you already have k to keep track of everything. Just be careful because k starts at 0, so make sure you add 1 to your number of runs if using k.